# regsiter a new user through WordPress API with Google SSO doesn't work properly

Tags: php, rest-api, authentication

I have a code that sends a Google's user  data from NodeJS to WordPress and I can see the email registered but first of all it doesn't do auto-login and doesn't set a Name so I just see the email who got sent and to page I created in WordPress and the code just create a user using the email but it doesn't log him in or set any cookies.

So even these posts that supposed to be created, the code doesn't create any of them

```php
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
            // User is logged in
            // Log or debug as needed
            $regex = '(\b16-\d{3}\b)';
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => 'Test regex',
                'post_content' => $regex,
                'post_type' => 'post',
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
        } else {
            $regex = '(\b16-\d{3}\b)';
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title' => 'Test regex false',
                'post_content' => $regex,
                'post_type' => 'post',
            );`
```

```php
    function handle_registration_callback()
    {
        $request_body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); // Get JSON data from the request body
    
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($request_body['email'])) {
            // Validate and sanitize input data
            $email = sanitize_email($request_body['email']);
            $display_name = sanitize_text_field('mostafa');
            $password = wp_generate_password();
    
            // Create WordPress user
            $user_id = wp_create_user($email, $password, $email);
    
            // Set display name
            wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $display_name));
    
            // Log in the user
            wp_set_current_user($user_id);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            do_action('wp_login', $email);
            error_log('User ID: ' . $user_id);
            error_log('Email: ' . $email);
            error_log('Before wp_insert_post - User ID: ' . $user_id);
            $regex = '(\b16-\d{3}\b)';
            $my_post = array(
                'post_title' => 'Test regex',
                'post_content' => $regex,
                'post_type' => 'post',
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
            error_log('After wp_insert_post - User ID: ' . $user_id);
            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                // User is logged in
                // Log or debug as needed
                $regex = '(\b16-\d{3}\b)';
                $post_data = array(
                    'post_title' => 'Test regex',
                    'post_content' => $regex,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                );
                $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
            } else {
                $regex = '(\b16-\d{3}\b)';
                $post_data = array(
                    'post_title' => 'Test regex false',
                    'post_content' => $regex,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                );
                $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
                // User is not logged in
                // Log or debug as needed
            }
            // Redirect to a specific URL after successful login
            wp_safe_redirect('https://rhbshop.codeforsite.com/'); // Change the URL as needed
            exit;
        } else {
            // Send an error response if needed
            wp_send_json_error();
        }
    }
    
    add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    
    
        register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/register-endpoint', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'handle_registration_callback',
        ));
    });
```

Edit debug.log

```
#3 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-content/plugins/printify-api/index.php(397): do_action('wp_login', 'programermostaf...')
#4 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1193): handle_registration_callback(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#5 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1041): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request(Object(WP_REST_Request), '/custom/v1/regi...', Array, NULL)
#6 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(431): WP_REST_Server->dispatch(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#7 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/rest-api.php(424): WP_REST_Server->serve_request('/custom/v1/regi...')
#8 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): rest_api_loaded(Object(WP))
#9 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#10 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#11 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp.php(418): do_action_ref_array('parse_request', Array)
#12 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp.php(813): WP->parse_request('')
#13 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/functions.php(1336): WP->main('')
#14 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#15 /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/index.php(17): require('/home/dh_vzrang...')
#16 {main}
```

Comment: How would it even be possible to log them in if the data is coming from a Node server? The user isn't present when any of this code is run.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I send a post request from NodeJS to WordPress, the post request contains the username and email, so I want to create is when the user login/register in the nodejs website the data will be sent to the wordpress website through wordpress api 

So it's Multi-Domain SSO between nodejs and wordpress  and login through  `do_action('wp_login', $email);`

Comment: I already receive the request on the wordpress website when I login through the nodejs website but other functionalities like set cookies and login the user through the wp_login doesn't work, actually more indeed after the user got created nothing works.

Comment: how are you testing this? It looks like you create a user, then attempt to log them in, then try to test if the user is logged in all in the same request sequentially, and you're using the final output to determine if it worked or not rather than testing each step individually and separately, making it super confusing. Can you include debug data and rewrite the text so it isn't 1 super long sentence? It's quite difficult to understand what's going on. Paragraphs and sentences will help enormously. Remember most people won't read the comments so your question needs to contain everything

Comment: @TomJNowell Sorry about that, I'll edit the question also and add all the details overalll what I want to do that I have Google SSO on NodeJS and Single tab on plugin on Wordpress, I want to have multi SSO between the NodeJS and WordPress that the user when register on NodeJS he'll find him self registered as well on the WordPress website. So after the user register on NodeJS I redirect the user to the WordPress website and supposed to find him self registered/logged in as well.

Comment: I added the log and by the way this code is on a plugin on the WordPress site

Comment: I'm not seeing any of the `error_log` statements, just a stack trace with the error message and the first 3 lines missing ( the most useful parts! )

Comment: right before this debug there's only this error  
`15-Jan-2024 15:07:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wc_maybe_store_user_agent(), 1 passed in /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 324 and exactly 2 expected in /home/dh_vzrang/rhbshop.codeforsite.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-user-functions.php:919
Stack trace:` and by the way have Woocommerce plugin and another one for Google SSO login its name is `Single Tab On`

Comment: @TomJNowell Hi sorry for mentioning this again, currently the code works and I can see the user logged already in the back-end but not logged on the front-end for example when the post gets created, it did create under the new user but on the front-end no one is logged, I use Woocommerce and Google Tab On forms for login.

Comment: I'm edit the post also and update it with the new edits so overall the task is Cross SSO domain between NodeJS website and Wordpress (I saw some articles says that cookies doesn't get shared unless it's not on the same host)

Comment: I hadn't looked at this since my last comment, and the mention of a WooCommerce function is extremely concerning as questions about 3rd party plugins such as WooCommerce are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. It's extremely unlikely you can get help unless you ask this in a community with people knowledgable about WooCommerce and the login solution you're using. I'm unsure if this question is appropriate for this stack

Comment: also yes, if they're different domains then that'd be a 3rd party cookie. Right now it looks like your question will need extensive edits to make it clear and on topic, it's missing a lot of information that you've shared in the comments, and it was also missing a lot of formatting that I had to guess and edit in myself. There's also no information about where the code is located in the codebase, the payload the REST API endpoint receives, what makes the request ( is it the Node app or does the Node app redirect the user there? ) etc. From your last comment it could just be caching